# Why is the Linux command `unshare --pid=p --mount=m` not creating a persistent namespace?

Tags: linux, lxc, namespace, container, unshare

From everything I have read in the `unshare` and `nsenter` man pages, I should be able to bind-mount a directory to itself, `mount --make-private` the directory, and then use files within that directory to hold refs for persistent namespaces.  Here is what I'm doing, basically the same as the `man unshare` but with different directories and using `--pid=file` in addition to `--mount=file`

## Terminal 1:

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns
# mount --bind /mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns /mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns
# touch /mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/{mount,pid}
# mount --make-private /mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns
# unshare --fork --mount-proc --mount=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/mount --pid=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/pid /bin/sh & echo $!; fg
[1] 151299
151299
sh-4.4# echo $$
1
sh-4.4# grep NS /proc/self/status
NStgid: 3
NSpid:  3
NSpgid: 3
NSsid:  0
```

So far so good, the container above is working.  While that runs:

## Terminal 2:

```
# nsenter  --mount=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/mount --pid=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/pid /bin/sh
sh-4.4# ps ax
Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc
# ls /proc/1/exe -l
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Jul 21 18:49 /proc/1/exe -> /usr/bin/bash
sh-4.4# mount -t proc proc /proc
sh-4.4# ps ax|head
<shows pids from the host OS, not from the container>
sh-4.4# grep NS /proc/self/status
NStgid: 156987
NSpid:  156987
NSpgid: 156987
NSsid:  156921
```

I've also tried this in Terminal 2 (note the pid from Terminal 1) with the exact same results:

```
# nsenter -t 151299 -a  /bin/sh
sh-4.4# ps ax
Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc
# ls /proc/1/exe -l
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Jul 21 18:49 /proc/1/exe -> /usr/bin/bash
sh-4.4# mount -t proc proc /proc
sh-4.4# ps ax|head
<shows pids from the host OS, not from the container>
sh-4.4# grep NS /proc/self/status
NStgid: 155356
NSpid:  155356
NSpgid: 155356
NSsid:  143538
```

For some reason `nsenter` is entering the host OS's pid space, however it does seem to see a the namespace of the correct /proc directory, but it is invalid for `sh` in terminal2 because the pid namespace isn't working so (I think) thats why `ps ax` gives an error.  Also I've tried both with and without --mount-proc

## Questions:

How can I enter the PID namespace from Terminal 1?

What am I doing wrong here?

(Host linux kernel is 5.18 running Oracle Linux 8.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug between before util-linux v2.36 that was patched in this commit:

[0d5260b66 unshare: Fix PID and TIME namespace persistence](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/commit/0d5260b66c5581c8a5855a5f49e298e48e8baf82)

Use a version of util-linux containing the patch!

Here is a test-script to verify if you have this bug:

```bash
umount -l /mnt/jails/*/*/.ns/* /mnt/jails/*/*/.ns/
sleep 1

mkdir -p /mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns
mount --bind /mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns /mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns
touch /mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/{mount,pid}
mount --make-private /mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns

unshare --fork --mount-proc --mount=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/mount --pid=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/pid sleep 99 &
upid=$!

sleep 1

if nsenter --mount=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/mount --pid=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/pid [ -d /proc/self ]; then
    kill $upid
    echo worked
    exit 0
else
    kill $upid
    echo didnt
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I am suspicious of this business:

```
...  /bin/sh & echo $!; fg
```

That seems to always end up with the shell exiting and my terminal in a weird state. So don't do that; just run:

```
unshare --fork --mount-proc --mount=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/mount --pid=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/pid
```

Now you have a shell running in its own mount and pid namespaces.

---

> I've also tried this in Terminal 2 (note the pid from Terminal 1) with the exact same results:

We discussed this [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710989/4989); your life will be simpler if you stop mucking about with process ids, especially since you've already gone to the effort of creating persistent namespaces. Intead of `-t <pid>`, use those persistent namespaces you created:

```
# nsenter --mount=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/mount --pid=/mnt/jails/debian/bookworm/.ns/pid
# ps -fe
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 16:45 pts/4    00:00:00 /bin/sh
root           3       0  1 16:48 pts/15   00:00:00 -bash
root          41       3  0 16:48 pts/15   00:00:00 ps -fe
```

As you can see, we've successfully entered the namespaces created by the earlier `unshare` command.

Comment: I will also add the while I don't know exactly what you're doing, in most cases, using a container runtime like Podman or Docker (or even [`systemd-nspawn`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html)) is generally an easier way to isolate things in their own namespace.

Comment: Well, I've run your commands verbatim but when I do ps -fe I get `Error, do this: mount -t proc proc /proc`, so its not keeping the mount namespace.  After I do mount /proc, then `ps -fe` shows host pids not container pids.

Comment: This works where 4078670 is the child pid: `nsenter --mount=/proc/4078670/ns/mnt --pid=/proc/4078670/ns/pid` but I'm pretty sure thats the same as `nsenter -t 4078670 -a` and the whole point is we're trying to do this without pids, so if you have any ideas then I would be grateful.

Comment: Ok, so actually it was a bug in unshare, see the answer referencing the github commit.