# How do you get the child pid of `unshare` when using --fork for `nsenter -t <pid>`?

Tags: linux, namespace, unshare

When using `unshare --pid --fork`, the `nsenter` command must attach to the child pid not the `unshare` pid to get to the right pid namespace.

I can get unshare's pid as follows:

```bash
unshare --pid --mount --fork --mount-proc  bash & 
echo PID: $!
fg
```

but I need `unshare`'s child's pid (2914003) to enter the right namespace:

```
ps wwfuax | grep -A1 unshare 
2914002 pts/4    S      0:00  |           \_ unshare --pid --mount --fork --mount-proc bash
2914003 pts/4    S+     0:00  |               \_ bash
```

This works: `nsenter -t 2914003`
This does not: `nsenter -t 2914002`

I was hoping for some kind of option like `unshare --show-child-pid` but there isn't.

What is a nice reliable way to get unshare's child's pid?

Comment: Does `pgrep -P pid-of-parent-process-here` find the right pid (or pids)?

Comment: @thrig Changing it into `pgrep -o -P pid-of-parent-process-here` will give just one: the first (which will be pid 1 inside)

Comment: @thrig, it does!  Awesome, I didn't know that pgrep trick.  A.B gives a good -o option, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution is to not rely on process ids.

When you use the unshare command to create namespaces, you can create persistent namespaces that are referred to by a bind mount on the filesystem. We can set that up following the example in the `unshare(1)` man page.

First, we need to set up a mountpoint with `private` propagation:

```
mkdir /tmp/ns
mount --bind /tmp/ns /tmp/ns
mount --make-private /tmp/ns
```

And then we need target files for our mount and pid namespaces:

```
touch /tmp/ns/{mnt,pid}
```

Now we create our namespaces with the `unshare` command:

```
unshare --pid=/tmp/ns/pid --mount=/tmp/ns/mnt --fork --mount-proc  bash
```

Using those reference mountpoints, we can enter the namespaces with no knowledge of process ids:

```
nsenter --mount=/tmp/ns/mnt --pid=/tmp/ns/pid
```

When you're done, don't forget to clean up:

```
umount /tmp/ns/{mnt,pid}
```

Comment: Nice one. I was stuck by the fact that /proc in the correct namespace(s) was not available to retrieve this information beside /proc/PID/ns/pid_for_children which gives only the pid namespace and isn't useful without its associated mount namespace.

Comment: I think thats what I was trying here, can you check this question and see what I was doing wrong: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710809/why-is-the-linux-command-unshare-pid-p-mount-m-not-creating-a-persistent-n